# Changing the word on the right of the window's name

Tags: tmux

Here is my display when I hit <kbd>META</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

```
(0)  - code: 2 windows (attached)
(1)  ├─> 0: vim-M (1 panes) "x230"
(2)  └─> 2: node* (1 panes) "��{d6�ME?�g��a���"
```

I'm wanting to know how to fix the `��{d6�ME?�g��a���`

I can

- Rename the session "code" at the top with <kbd>META</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd>
- Rename the window "node" at the left with <kbd>META</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

But I have no idea what that string inside `"` is even supposed to be in the top where it's x230, that's my hostname. I don't see a rename-hostname feature so I'm not sure how it got changed to change it back.

Answer (score 0):

This is the name of the terminal. I was able to change it by doing

```
printf '\033]2│%s\033\\' 'My Terminal Title'
```